# No print preview in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

Why can't I see the print preview/can't I print this page with Chrome:

http://www.tuxx.nl/bellen/buitenland/collect_call/print/

It's just HTML, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable Print Preview in `about:flags`:

http://maketecheasier.com/enable-disable-google-chrome-print-preview/2011/04/13

Comment: But why can't I even press the 'Print' button??

Comment: It is working when you do CTRL+P, but not when you press the print 'button' on the page. Why??

Comment: I can press that button to print, on Google Chrome 13.0.782.218 for Mac. You may have some extension blocked/disabled related javascript.